# Where are these cliffs?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, scotland

Does anyone knows where are these cliffs from the photo below?
All the information I have is that the photo is from [YouTube Video Tom Misch - The Journey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixn1r_JHLIw) and that at the bottom of the video is written "Photo by Richard Gaston
http://richardgaston.com".
I searched all over this Richard's website, but no photos of these cliffs were found. I also wrote him an email and texted him over Instagram, but you know it already, 0% success rate.

[image]

Comment: I suspect the west coast of Ireland or possibly Great Britain.

Comment: I was thinking the same about Moher, but just wasn't.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As usual, a reverse Google image search yields more information, as it points to [this page about Richard Gaston](https://impakter.com/exploring-photography-interview-richard-gaston/) which has the original picture, with a caption saying that this is Ramasaig, in Scotland.

Comment: I can't believe it! 
I did reverse google image search several times and all I was able to get is just a link back to Youtube Video. Thank You Sir a hundred times!

Comment: Yeah, the reverse Google image search didn't work for me either.  Some kind of dark magic is afoot.

Comment: I had to skip a page or two of links back to the same video and copies of it, but nothing magic :-)

Comment: @jcaron Seeing how most people use google these days going to the second page of search results is dark magic :-)